# c++ save file address to char[]

Tags: c++

I have a problem that if I want to save

```
char FileDirect[] = "C:\\Program Files\\"
```

so using the `cout` print me this

> C:\Program Files\

[image]

and edit this text also does not work

```
char File[MAX_PATH], FileEdit[MAX_PATH], MoveDirect[MAX_PATH] = "C:\\Program Files\\";
short Seartch = 0, Slash = 0, MoveDirectChar = strlen(MoveDirect);
cout << MoveDirect << "\n";
GetModuleFileName(NULL, File, MAX_PATH);
for (int i = 0; i < 260; i++)
{
    if (File[i] == '\\')
    {
        FileEdit[i + Slash] = '\\';
        ++Slash;
        ++Seartch;
        FileEdit[i + Seartch] = File[i];
    }
    else
    {
        FileEdit[i + Seartch] = File[i];
    }
}
for (int i = 260; i > 0; i--)
{
    if (File[i] == '\\')
    {
        for (int b = 0; i < 260; b++)
        {
            ++i;
            ++MoveDirectChar;
            MoveDirect[MoveDirectChar] = File[i];
        }
        break;
    }
}
MoveFile(FileEdit, MoveDirect);
cout << File << "\n";
cout << FileEdit << "\n";
cout << MoveDirect << "\n";
cin.get();
return 0;
```

Comment: You really should use a [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) if you are working with strings.

Comment: But if I use string so I do not know how to edit the text

Comment: If you use a string, you can just append to the string with `MoveDirect += File[i];`

Comment: Why don't you just use `strcat(MoveDirect, &File[i])`?

Comment: What is the actual problem? Why are you parsing strings manually like this at all? There are plenty of functions available for parsing/generating filesystem paths into/from their constituent components. And why are you doubling the slashes in the string data? You should not be doing that at all! Double-slashes are only meant to be used for string literals, not the actual runtime data.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I removed almost everything. I bad understand how it works therefore it was difficult. My problem is that: I do not know how i can on end MoveDirect add program name because without it I do not can move it with command MoveFile

Comment: If I am reading your code right, it looks like you are trying to move the calling program's file (`ConsoleApplication1.exe`) to the `C:\Program Files\` folder. Is that right? It does not really make sense to move the calling program's file while it is still running, so what are you REALLY trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am reading your code right, it looks like you are trying to extract the calling program's filename (`ConsoleApplication1.exe`), append it to the end of the `MoveDirect` buffer (`C:\Program Files`), and then move the program's file to that new filename (`C:\Program Files\ConsoleApplication1.exe`).

If so, then your first loop can be replaced with the Win32 API [`PathFindFileName()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773589.aspx) function, and the second loop can be replaced with the [`PathAppend()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773565.aspx) function.

```
#include <Shlwapi.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "Shlwapi.lib")

char File[MAX_PATH];
char MoveDirect[MAX_PATH] = "C:\\Program Files\\";

GetModuleFileNameA(NULL, File, MAX_PATH);
PathAppendA(MoveDirect, PathFindFileNameA(File));
MoveFileA(File, MoveDirect);

cout << File << "\n";
cout << MoveDirect << "\n";

cin.get();
return 0;
```

Comment: This exactly I needed. Thanks for help